# c++ count algorithm template called by Rcpp

Tags: c++, rcpp

C++ count algorithm called by Rcpp which can count the occurrences of a particular element in a vector. 
The template should be used. 
My attempt:

```
countRcpp <-'
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

  int val = as<int>(y);
  NumericVector xx(x);
  NumericVector::iterator iter;
  int m = 0;

  for(iter = xx.begin(); iter < xx.end(); iter++){
    if(*iter == val) ++m;}

  return(wrap(m));
'
countf <- cxxfunction(signature(x = "numeric", y = "numeric"),
                      body = countRcpp,
                      plugin = "Rcpp")

set.seed (1005) # set seed for sampling
x <- sample(1:5L, size = 10, replace = T) #L is Long integer. Keep the nunmber as integer. 
x # [1] 1 3 1 3 3 4 1 3 1 2
y <- 3L
y
countf(x,y) 


incl <- '
#include<iostream>
#include <algorithm>  
#include <vector> 
using namespace std;

  template <typename S_Type, typename T>
  typename iterator_traits<S_Type>::difference_type 

  S_Type countR(S_Type first, S_Type last, const T & val){
    typename iterator_traits<S_Type>::difference_type ret=0;
    while (first !=last){
    if(*first == val) ++ret;
    ++first;
    }
  return ret;
  }
'
body_count <- '
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <algorithm>    

using namespace std;

  NumericVector xx(x);
  int n = xx.size();
  NumericVector yy = xx + n;
  int val = as<int>(y);
  int pos = countR(xx, yy, val);
  return wrap(pos);
'
countRcpp3 <- cxxfunction(signature(x = "numeric", y = "numeric"),
              body = body_count,
              includes = incl,
              plugin = "Rcpp")
```

Could you please give me any suggestions? Or would you recommend other logical on this task? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you not just use `std::count`/`std::count_if`?

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for your reply. std::count/std::count_if  is a good solution. While, I am a new learner on C++.  and really wish to fix my above algorithm to make it work.

Comment: You could also use the newer format via `Rcpp::sourceCpp()` -- please look at the [Rcpp Attributes](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-attributes.pdf) vignette for details.  It allows you to have the header, your function (and even R test code) in one file.

Comment: I looked at your for a moment and cannot make sense of what you are trying to do there with your templates. My recommendation:  get something _much simpler_ working first.  There are also run-time / compile-time differences when working with R and Rcpp due to the underlying `SEXP` type.

Comment: Amy, you might want to double-check with your university whether asking these questions violates their code of conduct. Quoting a deleted answer from @nailimp: "the asker of the question is violating the code of conduct of the university she (Amy?) is attending. I wanted to politely ask for the question to be taken down. If you can't take it down I will then inform the TA that the end of semester evaluation question has been compromised." I'm not taking a side in this, but you might want to double-check what you're doing, just in case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a first step you can extract a function with signature

```
int foo(Rcpp::IntegerVector x, int val)
```

from your working code. You can then generalize this to act on any iterable type. Signature:

```
template <typename T>
int foo(T x, typename std::iterator_traits<typename T::iterator>::value_type val)
```

One cannot call this from R, though. If the function in R should act on different types, it has to take `SEXP` as argument. `TYPEOF()` can then be used to determine the R data type. Putting this together for integer vectors:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

template <typename T>
int iter_count(T x, typename std::iterator_traits<typename T::iterator>::value_type val) { 
  int m = 0;

  for(typename T::iterator iter = x.begin(); iter < x.end(); ++iter) {
    if(*iter == val) ++m;
 }

  return m;
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
int count(SEXP x, SEXP val) {
  switch( TYPEOF(x) ) {
  case INTSXP: {
    return iter_count(Rcpp::as<Rcpp::IntegerVector>(x),
              Rcpp::as<Rcpp::IntegerVector>(val)(0));
  }
  default: {
    Rcpp::stop("incompatible SEXP encountered");
  }
  }  
}


/*** R
set.seed (1005)
x <- sample(1:5L, size = 10, replace = T)
y <- 3L
count(x,y) 
*/
```

I am using Rcpp attributes here: Save this as a `.cpp` file and use `Rcpp::sourceCpp("...")` on it.

BTW, in your code this looks fishy:

```
  NumericVector xx(x);
  int n = xx.size();
  NumericVector yy = xx + n;
```

Do you want the end-point of `xx`? Then use `xx.end()` or `end(xx)`, which is not a `NumericVector`. Your code creates a new `NumericVector` where the content of `xx` has been incremented by the size of `xx`. Here the equivalent code using Rcpp attributes:

```
Rcpp::cppFunction('NumericVector foo(NumericVector xx) {
  int n = xx.size();
  NumericVector yy = xx + n;
  return yy;
}
')

set.seed(42)
foo(runif(3))
# [1] 3.914806 3.937075 3.286140
```

Comment: My feeling too: the original question is underspecified and goes a little crazy on mixing indexing and iterators as well as different types. Beyond repair unless OP comes back and cleans up.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel The original code was a mess. The updated code made the intention clearer, which allowed for an expanded answer while you commented ...

Comment: Nice, and pretty close to eg the standard 'dispatch at run-time' examples [eg at the Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/rcpp-wrap-and-recurse/).

Comment: @RalfStubner Many thanks for your answer which is really helpful and satisfies the requirement very well. While, I don't know how this `(0)` works in here:  `Rcpp::as<Rcpp::IntegerVector>(val)(0));` , could you tell me?

Comment: @Amy_777 This selects the first element from the IntegerVector created from val. This is necessary since there is no SEXP that represents a single value. The best you can do is a vector with length one.